# Facebook SDK 3.1 - send app requests

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible to send app requests using the Facebook SDK of iOS 3.1?

The documentation Facebook provides doesn't work with the new SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Here are the issues:

1) the documentation tells you to import Facebook.h and create an Facebook instance. This is not how they tell you to create a FB connection using 3.1

2) You cannot import Facebook.h with the new SDK

3) However, you can import Facebook.h with the new SDK if you import the deprecated headers into the app

4) Once you import the deprecated headers into the app and follow the instructions on the above link, you discover dozens of fatal errors (redefinitions/duplicate declarations).

I've been looking around for quite some time and cannot find any solution for this. At least I have found others struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all the errors by not having `#import "Facebook.h"` and `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` in the same file.

Anyway this way of supporting good features like app-requests sucks!

Answer (score -2):

I use CocoaPods.org and let it do all the hard work for me :D

http://www.cocoapods.org

Comment: Why two down votes? He's asking how to install Facebook SDK. Just use Cocoapods. Done :D